# In firefox, how to adjust window size, location per site basis

Tags: ubuntu, firefox

I'm using Firefox as my default browser. I already have a plugin which remembers the text size from my previously used zoom % per site basis.

Now I want to take this one step further. There are times certain sites are best viewed in different windows sizes. I browse reddit with 50% width snapped to the left while I browse others maximized.

Now how do I configure Firefox to remember & retain the window position & size based on the site I'm browsing?

Comment: You don't because it has no such feature.

Comment: How would that handle different sites loaded in tabs in the same window?

Comment: @xenoid obviously it would be based on the active tab

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest extension I can find to do this: [Zoom Page WE](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/zoom-page-we/)